# JavaScript replace string globally

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am having the following JavaScript variable:

```
var keywords = split_option_value[3];
```

that returns on `console.log(keywords);` the below string:

```
seo|drupal|seo marketing|wordpress|web development|web design|plugin
```

I want to use the replace function to remove the straight line and add a comma instead. For that I am using:

```
var good_keywords = keywords.replace(/|/g, ',');
```

Unfortunately this isn't working like it should receiving on `console.log('good_keywords')`:

```
,s,e,o,|,d,r,u,p,a,l,|,s,e,o, ,m,a,r,k,e,t,i,n,g,|,w,o,r,d,p,r,e,s,s,|,w,e,b, ,d,e,v,e,l,o,p,m,e,n,t,|,w,e,b, ,d,e,s,i,g,n,|,p,l,u,g,i,n,
```

What is the problem with my code that generates this issue and what did I do wrong? Any guidance and help is more than welcomed.

Comment: The vertical bar `|` has special meaning in regexes. Escape it with a backslash `\\`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you very much. This solve my problem. I wasn't thinking that the specific character has a special meaning in regexes. :)

Comment: are you sure you want to use regular expressions? It looks like a bit of a overhead for this task

Comment: @dirluca What other alternative could you propose?

Comment: use a string as first parameter of replace, the replace will be performed plain and not as regexp

Comment: In this case you could use `keywords.split('|').join(',')` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe char `|`:

`var good_keywords = keywords.replace(/\|/g, ',');`

*Just as @Frédéric Hamidi offered in his comment.*

p.s.: because now your regexp means `find all ("empty characters" OR "empty characters")`, and that's exactly why you receive commas between all your characters.

Answer (score 2):

When using Regular Expressions, the `|` character is considered a special character and must be escaped to be interpreted literally.

Try:

```
var good_keywords = keywords.replace(/\|/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe `|` is a regexp character. It's used to accept two syntaxes. For example : `/a|b/g` is about to match `a` or `b` in string. 
You should use instead `/\|/g`.